# Jest testing error Received: serializes to the same string

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

i try to play with jest to learn how to test my react application.
I have create a button that will only embed some element to keep the same style constantly.

Here is the code of my button :

```
export function searchBtn(triggerSearch) {
  return (
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center my-3">
      <input
        type="submit"
        className="btn btn-primary w-25"
        value="Search"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          triggerSearch();
        }}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my test :

```
const { searchBtn } = require("./SearchBtn");

test("going to try the btn", () => {
  
  function triggerSearch() {}

  expect(searchBtn(triggerSearch)).toEqual(
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center my-3">
      <input
        type="submit"
        className="btn btn-primary w-25"
        value="Search"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          triggerSearch();
        }}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
});
```

I don't know why i always get this error : 
**Received: serializes to the same string**

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

```
const { searchBtn } = require('./SearchBtn');

describe('65737249', () => {
  test('going to try the btn', () => {
    function triggerSearch() {}
    expect(JSON.stringify(searchBtn(triggerSearch))).toEqual(
      JSON.stringify(
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center my-3">
          <input
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-primary w-25"
            value="Search"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              triggerSearch();
            }}
          ></input>
        </div>
      )
    );
  });

  test('better', () => {
    function triggerSearch() {}
    expect(searchBtn(triggerSearch)).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <div
        className="d-flex justify-content-center my-3"
      >
        <input
          className="btn btn-primary w-25"
          onClick={[Function]}
          type="submit"
          value="Search"
        />
      </div>
    `);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65737249/SearchBtn.test.jsx
  65737249
    ✓ going to try the btn (3 ms)
    ✓ better (8 ms)

 › 1 snapshot written.
Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot written from 1 test suite.

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   1 written, 1 total
Time:        4.946 s
```

Comment: Oh so you have to stringing it :0 , so it can be tested. Thank you